# What is origin of the phrase "as gay as cheese"?

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin, popular-refrains

A little while back, I was [trying to find an old Hitchcock anthology story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229535/alfred-hitchcock-anthology-story-involving-a-psychic-barber-who-is-bald-as-an-e) that turned out to be Joan Aiken's "[As Gay as Cheese](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?78453)" where the eponymous phrase is one of many that the main character uses to describe his generally positive mood. Someone jokingly asked just how gay cheese is, and I found myself stymied by almost no references to the phrase that are not about the story itself (closest I found was one person using the phrase with "gay" indicating homosexuality). Google Ngrams wasn't even of much use to trace how far back the phrase went, as it brings up no entries. If it helps, the main character is a Cornish barber, so I suppose it might be a regional phrase.

My central question is, is there a meaning to the phrase, like it referring to the bright color of some cheeses (playing off of the idea of brighter colors being considered happier colors) or is it intentionally random like "the cat's pajamas"?

Comment: [Strongly related](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2013/04/the-origin-of-say-cheese-and-when-people-started-smiling-in-photographs).

Comment: Bright and briesy.